# Is there a way to make data linked to by BCS look like a document library?

Tags: document-library, bcs, configuration

Is there a way to make the data linked to by BCS look like a document library?

Basically, I'm storing some archival type documents in cheaper storage than a SharePoint document library, but I would like the present them as if they were in a document library when the user examines the contents of my list.

Comment: Can you use RBS instead?  That way, SharePoint will still think the content is "in SharePoint", and will behave the way you want, but the BLOBs will be diverted to the cheaper storage before it hits the SharePoint DBs.

Comment: The data lives behind a web service, unfortunately.